# Infinite Loop when opening file

Tags: python, file

Okay so I'm trying to write a script that takes two files and modifies the first before writing it into the destination fine, but whenever I run it, the script only prints the first modified line over and over again.

```
#3a
def modify(string):
    """Takes a string and returns a modified version of the string using two modifications. One must be a replacement of some kind.

    string -> string"""
    while string != "":
        string = string.upper()
        string = string.replace("A","4").replace("B","8").replace("C","<").replace("E","3").replace("G","6").replace("I","1").replace("O","0").replace("R","|2").replace("S","5").replace("T","7").replace("Z","2")
        print(string)

#3b - asks the user to type in a source code filename and destination filename; opens the files; loops through the contents of the source file line-by-line, using modify() to modify eat line before writing it to the destination file; the closes both files.
source = input("What file would you like to use?")
destination = input("Where would you like it to go?")
filesource = ""

while filesource == "":
    try:
        file_source = open(source, "r")
        file_destination = open(destination, "w")
        for item in file_source:
            mod = modify(item)
            file_destination.write(mod)
        file_source.close()
        file_destination.close()
        break
    except IOError:
        source = input("I'm sorry, something went wrong. Give me the source file again please?")
```

Any help?

Comment: and how, do you think, `string` becomes an empty string in your while loop?

Comment: Similarly, how do you think `filesource` will ever be non-empty when you never assign anything to it?

Comment: I think you confused `if` with `while`. And your use of `filesource` looks like a type for an intended `file_source`.

Comment: Your output file will only contain the last modified line - do you see why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if you run `modify("TEST ME")` what does it return?

> add `return string` to the end of the `modify` function.

Answer (score 0):

The string never empties - try parsing through it char by char using an index int and your conditional being `while i < len(string)`